# create dummy for individuals with either of two conditions over two combined periods

Tags: stata, panel-data, dummy-variable

I am using Stata.

I am after a descriptive statistic gained from the TUS (i.e., Time Use Survey): the total daily time spent working for full-time workers (since these data are from Luxembourg, the working day is at least 8 hours long for full-time workers).
Therefore, I work on the subsample of TUS, where there are only people who declared to be employed.

In this (subsample of the) dataset, there are two observations per person, one on the week-end and one during the week (i.e., it is a sort of short panel dataset).

Since I am interested in just those people who work full-time, I want to measure the total working time over those two days for two types of individuals:

1. individuals who work during the week, for whom the working time is 8 or more hours on a week day and 0 on a weekend day (Saturday and Sunday);
2. individuals who work during the week and on weekends (e.g., waiters, nurses, drivers, etc...), for whom the working time is 8 or more hours on a week day and 8 or more hours on a weekend day.

**[Question 1]** How can I create a variable which is 1 when the individual is either 1. or 2. and 0 otherwise?

**[Question 2]** Once I have created that dummy variable for full-time workers, I would like to create another dummy variable which is 1 for workers who work only on week days and 0 for workers who work also on weekends, how could I do that?

**[UPDATE]**
Here I post a part of the dataset as example (obtained with datasex):

```
clear
input double(working_act1 working_act2 working_act3 working_act4) float weekend double  id_ind
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4015801
0 0                  0  .3333333333333339 11.666666666666668 0 4017501
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4017501
0 0                  0 .16666666666666785                  8 0 4017601
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4017601
0 0                  0                  0  8.166666666666668 0 4017602
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4017602
0 0                  0                  0  7.166666666666669 0 4017801
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4017801
0 0 .16666666666666785                  0  3.666666666666668 0 4017802
0 0                  0 .33333333333333215                  7 1 4017802
0 0                  0                  0 12.000000000000002 0 4018001
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4018001
0 0                  0                  0  6.333333333333332 0 4018002
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4018002
0 0                  0                  0   9.16666666666667 0 4019201
0 0                  0                  0   9.16666666666667 1 4019201
0 0 .16666666666666607                 .5  8.333333333333334 0 4019504
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4019504
0 0                  0                  0                6.5 0 4019901
0 0                  0                  0                  8 1 4019901
0 0                  0                  0  6.166666666666668 0 4020001
0 0                  0                  0                  0 1 4020001
end
```

Comment: Questions here should at least attempt some code. Otherwise you are best advised to show a data example. There is no reason to oblige other people to invent variable names, data examples, etc.: it is quite difficult for others to absorb a long word description Type `ssc inst dataex` to install a program, which makes it easy for you to give us a data example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion @NickCox!

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on the answer to my two questions for a few days now and soon after I have posted the question here, I found an answer, which I share with you.

**Points First to Third lead to the answer to question 1.; points Fourth and Fifth lead to the answer to question 2.**

First, I generate the total working daily time, which is given by the time spent on four mutually exclusive working activities (working_act1 working_act2 working_act3 working_act4); the variable weekend==1 when the observation refers to a weekend day and 0 otherwise

```
cap drop tsw
egen tsw        =   rowtotal(working_act1 working_act2 working_act3 working_act4)
label var tsw "Time spent working"
tab tsw if weekend==0
tab tsw if weekend==1
```

Second, I create a variable that tells me whether on a specific day a person either did not work or worked full-time

```
cap drop ft_workrest_day
gen ft_workrest_day = (tsw >=8) | tsw==0 if weekend==1
replace ft_workrest_day = (tsw >=8) if weekend==0
label var ft_workrest_day "Worked_8h or rested"
```

Third, I create a variable that equals 2 for people (i.e., the variable id_ind) who worked one day full-time and rested the other day as well as for people who worked on both days for all the other people this value is missing

```
cap drop ft_worker
bys id_ind: egen ft_worker = total(cond(ft_workrest_day>0, ft_workrest_day, .))
replace ft_worker = . if ft_worker==0 | ft_worker==1
label var ft_worker "Works at least 8h"
```

Fourth, I create a variable which equals 1 for ft_workers who worked in the w-e

```
cap drop we_worker_2
gen we_worker_2 = 0 if ft_worker==2 
replace we_worker_2 = 1 if tsw!=0 & ft_worker==2 & weekend==1
browse id_ind weekend tsw ft_workrest_day ft_worker we_worker_2
label var we_worker_2 "Works at least 8h in the w-e"
```

Fifth, I create a variable which equals 1 when a person worked full-time on both days, while equals 0 for people who worked full-time during the week day and rested in the w-e.

```
cap drop we_worker_1
bys id_ind: egen we_worker_1 = max(we_worker_2)
browse id_ind weekend tsw ft_workrest_day ft_worker we_worker_2 we_worker_1
label var we_worker_1 "Full-time w-e worker"
```

Comment: Pleased you solved your problem. If you're minded to make this more useful to others, you'll make it self-contained by including a token data example. What are the general ideas that travel? Note that `gen worker = work_stast == 0` is a more concise solution to your first point.

Comment: thanks for the message @NickCox. After I became accustomed with the dataex command (thanks for that too!) I have introduced a sample of the dataset in the question (see the **[UPDATE]**).

Comment: The example data and code still won't work together. No variable `work_stat` (or is it `work_stast`?). Hence code will fail at the first blick.